# Why is texture on different faces is not displaying properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a 3d model of my phone. I used different textures for the different faces of the phone. After rendering , as u can see in the image, the texture in not proper rectangle here, but it is rectangle in the edit mode.

What should I do get a proper rectangle on that face?

Please Help!

Comment: I do not understand the question well enough.  Please try to explain your situation differently.  Please show some uv maps and textures,

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Problem is solved. I closed it and started again and it worked. :)